# is there a good way to store vector data?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, vector-database

I had get a group of vector data(Data type: List) and I want to store it. I tried to use AWS DynamoDB but I find a problem that it only support List. Anyone knows how to store vector data in AWS platform or are there other recommend platform to store vector data? Thank you!

I am trying to store my vector data(List) into a cloud platform and I want to know can I use AWS? if not, are there other platform support storing vector data?

Answer (score 0):

This question will likely be closed as your asking for recommendations. But the 2 main databases handling vector data in AWS today is OpenSearch and Postgres (RDS Aurora).

Comment: Thank you for your reply? sorry I am new here, why asking for recommendations will be closed. And for the two products you mentioned, can these two store the vector data? or it just analysis data like Milvus?

Comment: You can also use Redis to store vectors, index them, and search for similarity using a couple of distance functions and approximation algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

https://neo4j.com now stores vector data, as does https://pinecone.io and https://weaviate.io which were designed for the use case.